# Calculating house down payment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.6

> You have graduated from MIT and now have a great job! You move to the San Francisco Bay Area and decide that you want to start saving to buy a house.  As housing prices are very high in the Bay Area, you realize you are going to have to save for several years before you can afford to make the down payment on a house. In Part A, we are going to determine how long it will take you to save enough money to make the down payment given the following assumptions:
>
> 1. Call the cost of your dream home total_cost​.
> 2. Call the portion of the cost needed for a down payment portion_down_payment​. For
>      simplicity, assume that portion_down_payment = 0.25 (25%).
> 3. Call the amount that you have saved thus far current_savings​. You start with a current
>      savings of $0.
> 4. Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of r ​(in other words,
>      at the end of each month, you receive an additional current_savings*r/12​ funds to put into
>      your savings – the 12 is because r​ is an annual rate). Assume that your investments earn a 
>      return of r = 0.04 (4%).
> 5. Assume your annual salary is annual_salary​.
> 6. Assume you are going to dedicate a certain amount of your salary each month to saving for 
>      the down payment. Call that portion_saved​. This variable should be in decimal form (i.e. 0.1
>      for 10%).
> 7. At the end of each month, your savings will be increased by the return on your investment, plus a percentage of your monthly salary ​(annual salary / 12).
>      Write a program to calculate how many months it will take you to save up enough money for a down payment. You will want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user inputs to floats

So far, I have this basic code:

```
annual_salary = float(input("Type annual salary here : "))
portion_saved = float(input("Type the portion you want to save (as a decimal)      : "))
total_cost = float(input("Type the cost of your dream house here : "))
monthly_salary = (annual_salary / 12.0)

portion_down_payment = 0.25 * total_cost

current_savings = 0 + ???

returns = (current_savings * 0.4) / 12

overall_savings = returns + (portion_saved * monthly_salary)

months = ???`
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to calculate the months.
I do not know if I need to create an IF statement, a loop, or none of them at all.

Comment: This shouldn't be difficult for an MIT graduate...

Comment: It sounds like you don't even know where to start. This site is, therefore, not appropriate for your needs, and you should seek out a tutoring service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free tutoring service.

Comment: A `while` loop is probably most appropriate here, or better yet, use the correct logarithm / exponential function to calculate the number of months in one go.

Comment: I am not enrolled in this class, nor do I go to MIT. I am taking it in my free time to learn code. I am not trying to get homework answers. I was interested in how to code this particular situation. I am a beginner, I am not looking for a tutor. I am looking for an explanation as to further my knowledge.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You down voted the question, recommended the question to be closed. Then why add another disparaging comment below. Seems a bit extreme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The months are the value it will take to reach your necessary amount.

For example, you want to loop up until you have enough for the down payment.

```
months = 0
# Want to exit the loop when there is enough savings for a down payment
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings +=  current_savings * (0.4 / 12)  # Monthly interest
    current_savings += portion_saved  # Monthly savings
    months += 1
print("It will take {} months to save!".format(months))
```

Comment: Thanks so much cricket. I will take your info and apply it best I can.

Comment: cricket, using the code you provided I was able to understand the problem entirely. thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

You just need a while loop:
Initialize the months variable to 0 and ensure that the savings don't exceed and is less than or equal to the down payment. Also ensure that you set Current Saving to 0 initially

```
Current_Saving=0
rate=0.04/12

monthly_savings = monthly_salary*0.1 

i=0
while (Current_Saving <= down_payment):
    Current_Saving = Current_Saving+(monthly_savings)*rate + monthly_savings 
    i=i+1
print(i)
```

I will give the total number of months. Monthly salary can be obtained by dividing the annual salary by 12.

Comment: just to let you know, this won't compile in python 3, print function must be called with parenthesis around the args.

Comment: Yes but the code pasted above shows - current_savings = 0 + ??? @Garret1021

Comment: I have edited the code, just re read the question. I multiplied the salary by 0.1 as 10 percent of the salary is saved each month

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved analytically.

```
down_payment_rate = 0.25
saving_rate = 0.10
r = 0.04 #investment rate

target = total_cost * down_payment_rate

M = annual_salary/12*saving_rate/12 #Monthly savings
```

The question is to solve the following:

```
target = M*(1+r) + M*(1+r)^2 + M*(1+r)^3 ...  M*(1+r)^N
```

The above is a geometric series, where N is the number of months to reach the target. This can be expressed succinctly as:

```
let g = 1+r:
target = M * (1-g^N)/(1-g)
```

You already know g, target, M, the only thing to solve for is N. you can find the result using algebra. Ie:  N = log(1-target*(1-g)/M)/log(g)